# R Import Excel file with values instead of formulas (multiple sheets)

Tags: r, import-from-excel

I'm trying to import a Excel sheet with a lot of formulas.

My goal is to read the values of the formulas.
I spent a lot of time here, searching for answers and already tried a lot, like using read.xlsx, read_excel, experimenting with the arguments, ... but I can't get it to work. I always receive either N/A or FALSE values instead of the formula value.

In my opinion a possible reason could be that the variables of the formulas are spread across various sheets. For example: I want to import the values of the formulas on sheet A. Some formulas on Sheet A need the results of other formulas on Sheet A, while these formulas need values from sheets B, C and D.

Could this be a possible reason for the non-working import and if so, how can I fix it?

I'm aware that I could solve this problem by opening the .xlsx in Excel and saving the formulas as values, but since the idea of my script is to automize a lot of processing steps, this solution would not be satisfying.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may not be due to scattered arguments of functions used on sheet onto many other sheets.  By any chance, values coming out of formulae in excel will be imported as values only and your formulae will not be imported as such in R.  You can however, recreate formulae as per R functions.
As regards your problem of import that may be due to incorrect use of arguments.  Try readr package